# When to use Core Data Relationships

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, one-to-one

I want to develop an application when the user enters a first name it is connected to a last name. Some both the first and last name are connected. Every first name has a last name and vice versa. Do I need to set up a relationship between entities to do this successfully. I added a photo of what I have in my core data so far. Seeking advice.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrDfu.png)

Comment: No those are attributes of the same entity (class), relationships are between different entities. I suggest you take the time to go through a tutorial on Core Data so you know the basics before proceeding.

Comment: So I would make 2 entits with a single attribute each one for first and the other for last

Comment: No, one entity with two attributes

Comment: It's like having `struct Person { let first: String; let last: String }`, does it make more sense to have that or `struct LastName { let value: String }; struct FirstName { let value: String }; struct Person { let first: FirstName; let last: LastName }`? Not really...

Comment: Unrelated, but don't name your class `Data`, Foundation has already a `Data`, and you'll have issues to disembiguate each time (because it won't know which `Data` you refers too).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I get what you saying but how would I create a situation where a first name is linked to a last name would I use a struct. Its like jessica alba is person 1 and gwen stefani is person 2. If I want to fetch person to what do I use?

Comment: @Larme  I get what you saying but how would I create a situation where a first name is linked to a last name would I use a struct. Its like jessica alba is person 1 and gwen stefani is person 2. If I want to fetch person to what do I use?